# C++ where to install/put dependencies best practices

Tags: c++, deployment, dependencies

I am planning to create a bigger C++ project. And I was wondering what are the best practices to install/put dependencies. I don't think that that best way is to put them is system32, or somewhere in C:\ while I'm working on the project in D:\

Is there a method to have all of them in the same place ?

Comment: Personal preference.  system32, no, don't do that.  Ever.  Personally I organise my projects with a Libraries folder.  That folder contains an I (for internal) and an E (for external) dependencies.  Internal dependencies are libraries I've written as part of the project.  External dependencies are things like Boost (if I'm using it).  The point is it's *all* contained in the main project folder, I, E, Build, everything.  You can move it around without having to change relative paths.

Comment: Use [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/)s

Comment: I am planing to use the ARToolkit 5.x librarry. So shoud i install it in .../project/Dependencies/External ? And OpenGL in the same place ?